# Building error in make step, gdk, libbat.la, MT_global_exit

Tags: build, makefile, gdk, monetdb

i'm trying to build MonetDB from source on CentOS. 
Typically the problems occur in the make step, 
I run the configuration as follows

./configure -prefix=$HOME/MonetDB--disable-geom --disable-strict

This works perfectly fine. However, using "make" afterwards leads to an error:

```
...
make[3]: Entering directory `/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MonetDB-11.19.9/gdk'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -DLIBGDK  -g -O2   -D_REENTRANT -version-info 11:4:0  -o libbat.la -rpath /users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MDB/lib libbat_la-gdk_batop.lo libbat_la-gdk_select.lo libbat_la-gdk_select_legacy.lo libbat_la-gdk_search.lo libbat_la-gdk_tm.lo libbat_la-gdk_align.lo libbat_la-gdk_bbp.lo libbat_la-gdk_heap.lo libbat_la-gdk_setop.lo libbat_la-gdk_utils.lo libbat_la-gdk_atoms.lo libbat_la-gdk_qsort.lo libbat_la-gdk_ssort.lo libbat_la-gdk_storage.lo libbat_la-gdk_bat.lo libbat_la-gdk_delta.lo libbat_la-gdk_cross.lo libbat_la-gdk_system.lo libbat_la-gdk_value.lo libbat_la-gdk_posix.lo libbat_la-gdk_logger.lo libbat_la-gdk_sample.lo libbat_la-gdk_calc.lo libbat_la-gdk_aggr.lo libbat_la-gdk_group.lo libbat_la-gdk_mapreduce.lo libbat_la-gdk_imprints.lo libbat_la-gdk_join.lo libbat_la-gdk_join_legacy.lo libbat_la-gdk_unique.lo libbat_la-gdk_firstn.lo  ../common/options/libmoptions.la ../common/stream/libstream.la ../common/utils/libmutils.la -lm  -lz   -lbz2  -pthread -ldl   
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libbat_la-gdk_batop.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_select.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_select_legacy.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_search.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_tm.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_align.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_bbp.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_heap.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_setop.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_utils.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_atoms.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_qsort.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_ssort.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_storage.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_bat.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_delta.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_cross.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_system.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_value.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_posix.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_logger.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_sample.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_calc.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_aggr.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_group.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_mapreduce.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_imprints.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_join.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_join_legacy.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_unique.o .libs/libbat_la-gdk_firstn.o  -Wl,--whole-archive ../common/options/.libs/libmoptions.a ../common/utils/.libs/libmutils.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MonetDB-11.19.9/common/stream/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MDB/lib ../common/stream/.libs/libstream.so -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lz -lbz2 -ldl  -O2 -pthread   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libbat.so.11 -o .libs/libbat.so.11.0.4
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/libbat_la-gdk_utils.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `MT_global_exit' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libbat.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MonetDB-11.19.9/gdk'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MonetDB-11.19.9/gdk'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/users/db01/dm/MonetDB/MonetDB-11.19.9'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found a similar error, containing MT_global_exit in the web: https://www.monetdb.org/pipermail/users-list/2014-June/007334.html

Trying the mentioned suggestion by deleting `__attribute__((__visibility__("hidden")))`
from the gdk/gdk_private.h was
lead to several different errors (in gdk_private.h) during the make process.

If you have any suggestions, I'd be happy to hear them!

best regards

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, which version of CentOS is this?